# Series $\sum nx^{n-1}$ uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

simple question I think:

I've gone quite a ways through a problem, and now have to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly on $[-a,a],\ (a < 1)$, where $f_n = nx^{n-1}$

I'm having problems. I have shown that its absolutely convergent with the ratio test, but I'm not certain where to go next - I've looked through all my notes and found something completely arcane involving:

$|\sum_{k=m+1}^n kx^{k-1}| < \epsilon$ implies $|\sum_{k=m+1}^n kx^{k-1}| <= \sum_{k=m+1}^n ka^{k-1}$ (looks like the Cauchy condition, but how was it applied?), but I failed to write down what direction any of the logic was going and it's just a mess. How do I get to there from here?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not true that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$. However, it is true that that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ on the interval $[-a,a]$ for any nonnegative $a<1$, which can be proved using the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Is there a difference? Hm. The next part of the problem is going to be tougher than I anticipated, but I'll get to that momentarily - how do we bound $nx^{n-1}$ properly? I haven't been able to find a working way...

Comment: Yes, there is a HUGE difference. Uniform convergence is all about which domain you're working on. Make sure you don't write that on an exam paper!!

Comment: Okay, darn for now how do I properly bound that function sequence?

Comment: Just notice that if $|x|<a$, then $|f_n(x)|$=|nx^{n-1}|<na^{n-1}$, and then apply the M-test.

Comment: Oh, the $M_n$ is allowed to depend on n? Didn't realize that. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can depend on $n$ but not $x$.